# HTML5 canvas & audio cross-browser compatibility

Tags: html, audio, canvas, cross-browser, compatibility

**Background**

I'm making a canvas game which assumes the user to be using a browser with native canvas support (no IE < 9 scripts or similar). The user is being shown a message with links to download the latest version of their browser if they don't have one. This is displayed through a message in the <canvas> content as follows:

```
    <canvas>
        Error message (upgrade... safer, faster, better... free...
                       ...play this awesome game... getfirefox.com)
    </canvas>
```

**Question**

Is it safe to assume that any browser supporting the <canvas> tag also supports the <audio> tag? Or will I need to add an extra error message with the risk of displaying two messages on top of each other? What I'm worried about is their screens getting cluttered up with error messages in case they don't have native support for audio, but they do for canvas.

I understand that all the latest versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera do support both canvas and audio, but I'm not sure about mobile browsers and "in-between versions" and such. Other ideas of approaches are also appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
  Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers that support `<canvas>` but not `<audio>` (according to [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)):

- Safari 3.2
- Opera Mini 5.0-6.0
- Opera Mobile 10
- Android Browser 2.1-2.2

**Alternative method**

Detect features with JavaScript:

- `<audio>`: `return !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;`
- `<canvas>`: `return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;`

And display messages accordingly.

See [The All-In-One Almost-Alphabetical No-Bullshit Guide To Detecting Everything](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html) for a full list. If you want an all-in-one library for HTML5 feature detection, try [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! 3 great bookmarks added.
It does seem to be a very minor issue then. I think I will use JavaScript to detect the features as you said, and in case there is canvas but no audio, I can display a custom message for Safari, Opera Mobile (Mini still lacks support according to opera.com) and Android.

Although I prefer not to make special-case solutions, I doubt that browsers currently supporting both elements would stop supporting one of them. In other words, probably no new browsers will be added to this list. Do you think that's safe to assume?

Thank you again!

Comment: Unless your message is dependent on these browsers, what do you care? That's whole point of JS feature detection, you worry about _features_ not _browsers_. That said, the safety of this assumption depends on how accurate/complete the When can I use... tables are, whether you are using the canvas text API and the audio format you are using (which can be detected as well).

Comment: That's true. I guess it's not a good idea to blindly trust them. I'm not entirely sure yet of exactly what will be implemented into the game as far as APIs and audio formats go, so I don't know yet. What I was thinking regarding browsers was that in our target group, the people that still haven't upgraded their browsers to support HTML5 probably needs very careful guidance with only 1 clickable link that they can easily recognize. Otherwise, my experience tells me that many of them would give up. Anyway, thank you so much for your responses, you've definitely helped me get on track! Thanks.